# jUnit tests for Game of Life java.lang.Assertion error

Tags: java, junit, conways-game-of-life

i wrote few tests for the Game of Life "nextFrame" method to see if the shapes such as pulsar, still and glider work as they have to. Seemingly the shapes are correct in the nextFrame but tests wont pass, perhaps someone can explain why these tests wont pass.

Heres the test example :

```
 @Test
public void pulsarWorksCorrectly() {
    Frame frame = getFrame("------",
                           "-XX---",
                           "-X----",
                           "----X-",
                           "---XX-",
                           "------");

    Frame expected = getFrame("------",
                              "-XX---",
                              "-XX---",
                              "---XX-",
                              "---XX-",
                              "------");

   assertThat(frame.nextFrame(), is(equalTo(expected)));
   assertThat(frame.nextFrame().nextFrame(), is(equalTo(frame)));
}
```

Tests output :

`java.lang.AssertionError`

Expected is 
   `<"------",
    "-XX---",
    "-XX---",
    "---XX-",
    "---XX-",
    "------">`

but: was 
    `<"------",
    "-XX---",
    "-XX---",
    "---XX-",
    "---XX-",
    "------">`

Its confusing because the expected one the gotten is exact same.

Heres the method which helps me in testing :

```
private Frame getFrame(String ... rows) {

    // help method which creates Frame object from String array so tests are easier to write

    int height = rows[0].length();
    int width= rows.length;
    Frame cell = new Frame(height ,width);
    char alive;
    for(int i = 0;i <= width-1;i++)
        for(int j = 0; j <= height-1;j++) {

            alive = rows[i].charAt(j);

             if (Character.toString(alive).equals("X"))
             {

                 cell.markAlive(i,j);

             }              
        }       
    System.out.println(cell.toString());
    return cell;
}
```

I also uploaded the Frame class code just in case, because im not sure where the issue can be http://pastebin.com/AqeMTPbQ

Comment: Did you implement `equals`? (and therefore `hashCode`)

Comment: I didnt create create equals method if u meant that

Comment: The `Frame` class needs to have an `equals` method, for this kind of test to work.  Otherwise, the assertions fall back on reference comparison - that is, two `Frame`s will only come out equal if they're the exact same object.

Comment: @JuunPeeter well then your objects are never equal to each other, so of course if you assert that they're equal, then they won't be.

Comment: Thanks got my answer!

Comment: Then please close the ticket so people don't keep spending time looking at it.